# Preferred way of declaring and converting primitives to strings

Tags: java

I have 3 options:

1. Declare `double member` and later when I have to pass `String` use `member + ""`.
2. Declare `double member` and later when I have to pass `String` use `Double.toString(member)`.
3. Declare `Double member = 0.0` and later when I have to pass `String` use `member.toString()`.

My opinions:

1. The shortest one. However, `member + ""` will be converted to `new StringBuilder().append(member).append("").toString()`, which seems not elegant.
2. In `Double.toString(member)` I don't like that it doesn't start from the word `member`, which is the most important. We only need to convert it. It's better if `member` is in the beginning, because I pay most attention to the beginning of word. Quick glance and I know "ah, ok I'm passing member". And with `Double.toString(member)` my very first concentration goes to "ah, ok... a Double, we are doing toString... of a member! Ah ok".
3. `member.toString()` looks fine and it can be typed even faster then + "", because of autocompletion in Eclipse. However, objects are much slower then primitives. [Reference.](http://simononsoftware.com/primitives-and-objects-benchmark-in-java/)

**What is the best option?** Maybe there are some other options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best all-round approach, which will work for anything, is:

```
String s = String.valueOf(x);
```

Here `x` can be a primitive or an object, which (importantly) may be `null`.

Edit:
The hackaliciuos way is:

```
X + "";
```

Although note that this is not very efficient, because it compiles to:

```
new StringBuilder().append(x).append("").toString();
```

And the call to `.append(x)` invokes `String.valueOf(x)` anyway.

---

Note that arrays need special treatment:

```
String s = Arrays.toString(array);
```

Comment: And an object may be null here which is a weakness of toString.

Comment: For primitives it calls the `toString()` of the corresponding wrapper class.

Comment: Was about to write another answer noting the array exception, but you've already got it. +1

Comment: Thank you, it's good. However I don't like that it starts with `String.valueOf` not with an actual important thing: `x`. A bit less readable to me then simple `x + ""` or `x.toString()`.

Comment: For double this call will auto-box before the call, which just generates garbage and takes time.  If it's code in an inner loop, it's worthwile to use `Double.toString(x)`.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk: you can use a static import and just write `String s = valueOf(x);`

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk, this is just Java's whacky type system where some things are objects and others aren't.  If you want uniform syntax, switch to Scala (for example).