# Concatenate chars to form String in java

Tags: java

Is there a way to concatenate `char` to form a `String` in Java?

Example:

```
String str;
Char a, b, c;
a = 'i';
b = 'c';
c = 'e';

str = a + b + c; // thus str = "ice";
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `StringBuilder`:

```
String str;
Char a, b, c;
a = 'i';
b = 'c';
c = 'e';

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(a);
sb.append(b);
sb.append(c);
str = sb.toString();
```

One-liner:

```
new StringBuilder().append(a).append(b).append(c).toString();
```

Doing `""+a+b+c` gives:

```
new StringBuilder().append("").append(a).append(b).append(c).toString();
```

I asked some time ago [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046668/preferred-way-of-declaring-and-converting-primitives-to-strings).

Answer (score 33):

Use `str = ""+a+b+c;`

Here the first `+` is `String` concat, so the result will be a `String`. Note where the `""` lies is important.

Or (maybe) better, use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Does StringBuilder offer any inherent advantages over `str = ""+a+b+c;`?

Comment: @mbehan, The compiler will likely optimize this approach into a StringBuilder.

Comment: `""+a+b+c` will give `new StringBuilder().append("").append(a).append(b).append(c).toString();`. Please read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046668/preferred-way-of-declaring-and-converting-primitives-to-strings

Comment: @JaredNielsen, one fewer item to concatenate, but negligible.  Probably best to go with whatever one finds more readable (or whatever fits with your companies conventions).

Answer (score 8):

You can use StringBuilder:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('a');
    sb.append('b');
    sb.append('c');
    String str = sb.toString()
```

Or if you already have the characters, you can pass a character array to the String constructor:

```
String str = new String(new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c'});
```

Comment: If you already have the characters, why not just `String str = "abc";` and avoid the verbosity of a literal char array and string instantiation?

Comment: @JustinC an example use case would be if you had variables holding characters and wanted to concatenate them.

Answer (score 3):

If the size of the string is fixed, you might find easier to use an array of chars.
If you have to do this a lot, it will be a tiny bit faster too.

```
char[] chars = new char[3];
chars[0] = 'i';
chars[1] = 'c';
chars[2] = 'e';
return new String(chars);
```

Also, I noticed in your original question, you use the **Char** class.
If your chars are not nullable, it is better to use the lowercase **char** type.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Character.toString(char)` method.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html):

```
char c = 'a';
String s = String.format("%c%c", c, 'b'); // s is "ab"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 str = String.valueOf(a)+String.valueOf(b)+String.valueOf(c);
```

Output:

```
ice
```