# Concatenating chars to a String - Using StringBuilder's append()

Tags: java

I was doing research on concatenating char primitive values to form a String and came across this post:

[Concatenate chars to form String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282368/concatenate-chars-to-form-string-in-java)

I understand that the correct way of producing the final String value is to use the toString() method, how come that if I do not use this method, I still get the same output. I would have thought the following code would output the heap address of the object sb but it still prints 'ice'.

Thank you.

```
public class CharsToString {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

    char a, b, c;
    a = 'i';
    b = 'c';
    c = 'e';

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(a);
    sb.append(b);
    sb.append(c);

    System.out.println(sb);
    }   
}
```

Comment: System.out.println(sb) is equal to System.out.println(sb.toString());. JVM will do it for you. You can create 2 simple classes: one with implemented toString, second without, and call println to bouth instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look what `System.out.println(sb);` actually does.
It calls in class `java.io.PrintStream` this method. (because a StringBuilder extends Object)

```
 public void println(Object x) {
        String s = String.valueOf(x);
        synchronized (this) {
            print(s);
            newLine();
        }
    }
```

And, `String.valueOf(x)` calls the `toString()` method on your `StringBuilder`.

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the input and MrSmith42 in particular for the extremely detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

The toString() method of the StringBuilder object is automatically called implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you check `System.out.println(Object obj);` `System.out` is a `PrintStream` and `println( Object obj )` on the `PrintStream` calls `String.valueOf( Object )`,

The `String.valueOf( Object )` calls `toString()` on the Object, so indirectly `System.out.println( StringBuilder sb )` calls `StringBuilder`'s `toString()`,

Now if your Object is other than `StringBuilder`, which doesn't have `toString()`, it will print  `getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`

Answer (score 0):

This is because method `toString()` is called implicitly.
Everytime, when you try to print object, it looks for toString() method.
In this case, `println` method accept Object and call String.valueOf(Object o) which return String value of Object.

Answer (score 0):

System.out is a PrintStream class. So you look at javadoc for println(Object) for that class you will get your answer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-. In short if you invoke method println with parameter that is not primitive and not a String it will print output of toString() method of your object. So in your case calling `System.out.println(sb.toString());` and `System.out.println(sb);` would have  identical result