# How can I combine multiple char's to make a string in java?

Tags: java, char

I have the following code:

```
char char1, char2, char3, char4;
char1 = 'a';
char2 = 'b';
char3 = 'c';
char4 = 'd';
```

I want to make a string that combines these chars in java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate chars to form String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282368/concatenate-chars-to-form-string-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use StringBuilder :

```
    final char[] arrayOfCharArray = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char subArray : arrayOfCharArray) {
  sb.append(subArray);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`String.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-char:A-) like this:

```
String string = String.valueOf(new char[]{char1, char2, char3, char4});
// => "abcd"
```